# Post JSON data to IFTTT in single url

Tags: html, json, post, ifttt

I am using IFTTT.com and on their webhooks page it says

> With an optional JSON body of:
>
> { "value1" : "", "value2" : "", "value3" : "" }

This works fine when I use curl.. however, for my application I can only call a single url. Does anyone know if this is possible in the format like;

```
https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/<keyword>/with/key/<key>/value1=blah&value2=blah
```

Comment: Are you saying you have a limitation of not being able to use an HTTP request body?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps.
I wanted to send 3 values via a single url and this is what worked for me.
https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/My_web_hook/with/key/My_Key?value1=11&value2=13&value3=17

Post JSON data to IFTTT in single url

I hope this helps.
I wanted to send 3 values via a single url and this is what worked for me.
https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/My_web_hook/with/key/My_Key?value1=11&value2=13&value3=17

My key was followed by a "?", (you have a "/") and then the values. The data 11,13,17 was received by my "webhook" and passed onto me in an email. This is what I wanted to happen.

This perhaps?
https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger//with/key/?value1=blah&value2=blah

I found help in another page here on Stack Overflow but unable to upvote yet. Look for "How to pass data to IFTTT WebHook?"